# Does Canada have 5-star buffets served daily and offering Chinese delicacies like those of Hong Kong hotels?

Tags: canada, food-and-drink

In Hong Kong, my friend  discovered  [buffets from 5-star hotel chains](https://en.yelp.com.hk/search?find_desc=Restaurants&start=0&cflt=buffets&l=g:114.1977310180664,22.315478617875282,114.14623260498047,22.267828941371743) served daily with  more food variety and higher quality than in Canada, including Chinese delicacies like Abalone, Fish Maw, and Sea Cucumber.

From hotel chains that lack any hotel in Canada:

- [Hotel Icon (Tsim Sha
  Tsui)'s](http://www.hotel-icon.com/dining/the-market) 'Market': lunch
  and dinner.
- [Mandarin Oriental Hong
  Kong's](https://en.yelp.com.hk/search?find_desc=Restaurants&start=0&cflt=buffets&l=g:114.1977310180664,22.315478617875282,114.14623260498047,22.267828941371743)
  Clipper Lounge: breakfast and dinner.
- [The Peninsula Hong
  Kong's](http://hongkong.peninsula.com/en/fine-dining/the-verandah-buffet)
  'Verandah': breakfast, lunch, and dinner.

From hotel chains that possess hotels in Canada:

- [Grand Hyatt Hong Kong's](http://www.hongkong.grand.hyattrestaurants.com/tiffin/default-en.html) Tiffin: lunch, dinner.
- [JW Marriott Hotel Hong Kong's](http://www.marriott.com/hotels/hotel-information/restaurant/hkgdt-jw-marriott-hotel-hong-kong/) JW Café: breakfast, lunch, and dinner.
- [Island Shanghai-La Hong Kong's](http://www.shangri-la.com/hongkong/islandshangrila/dining/restaurants/cafe-too/) CAFE TOO
- [Kowloon Shanghai-La Hong Kong's](https://www.shangri-la.com/hongkong/kowloonshangrila/dining/restaurants/cafe-kool/book-a-table/) Café Kool
- [W Hong Kong's](http://www.w-hongkong.com/kitchen) 'Kitchen': breakfast, lunch, and dinner.

Are such buffets offered in Canada? I conjecture not, as existing buffets in Canada,  smaller and limiting in choice, are offered only for festivals or for Sunday brunches.

Comment: P.S. The original has been bifurcated on [this advice](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82160/why-does-canada-lack-5-star-buffets-served-daily-in-the-style-of-hong-kong-hotel#comment190548_82160).

Comment: What on earth are the down votes about?  We are not all fast food junkies in too much of a hurry or too economically challenged to eschew some epicurean treasures. Some of us sybarites would totally love to tuck in to a quality spread.

Comment: @GayotFow Thanks for the support. Ironically, I do not frequent buffets as I eat little: I ask this for my grandparents who are more interested.

Comment: I've reformatted the post to make it more readable. I think it was part of the reason why people downvoted

Comment: I have always found food on the CPR to be well above expectations.

Comment: @JonathanReez  Thank you. I will not reverse this edit, but did previously as it changed the content.

Comment: Not sure what to answer here. Restaurants in 5-star hotels in Canada are rarely buffet style for dinner, although breakfast and lunch buffets are extremely common - but I suspect the questioner knows that already.

Answer (score 8):

As I'm sure the questioner knows, the best restaurants in five-star hotels in Canada are not usually buffet-style, at least for dinner. Breakfast and lunch buffets are common. Lunch buffets are usually aimed at a more casual or budget-conscious traveller. High-class buffets specifically for Sunday brunch are also frequent.

However there is one class of establishment that usually offers high-class buffet dining every day in Canada, and that is the **casino resort**. Here is [an example from Fallsview Casino Resort](https://www.fallsviewcasinoresort.com/dining/business/grand-buffet) in Niagara Falls. [Casino Rama](https://www.casinorama.com/Mobile/dine.aspx) also has a couple of every-day buffet dining options. Presumably these are for people who want to maximize their time at the gaming tables, but that's just my speculation.

Answer (score 6):

Elegant **Sunday brunch** buffets are not unheard of in Canada. For example, the [Old Mill restaurant](http://www.oldmilltoronto.com/services-amenities/services/food-menus/dining-room/sunday-brunch/) in Etobicoke (Toronto) serves one that I think was equal to or superior to the only one I have visited in Hong Kong at the Mandarin (so a limited data set, I'm afraid).

Daily dinner buffets tend to be served by chains and to be aimed more at gourmands, and to be lacking in quality, though few cover the really low end as you can find in the US (Golden Corral, for example with all-you-can-eat for around $8-$12). [Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_Restaurant) (no relation to the hotels) is an example of a typical one with Chinese-style food and some Western stuff aimed at kids. Indian food also lends itself to buffet style and there are some such establishments.